# How to get sid and rid on xmpp?

Tags: c#, xmpp

Im using strophe and ejabberd, How i could get the sid and rid, from c# but not using matrix in xmpp, im trying to use this but i doesn't seem to be working [Fast HTTP-PRE-BIND](http://metajack.im/2009/12/14/fastest-xmpp-sessions-with-http-prebinding/)

Comment: Hello there friends i found the solution Strophe.js when a connection is stablished the connection has three properties sid,rid and jid